# Subtracting Columns In R?

Tags: r

I'm extremely new to R and I am struggling with subtracting one column from another any help how do I do this? I'm trying to subtract Final densities for Sp1 and Initial Densities for Sp1 for the first  4 values but then subtract Sp2 final densities from sp2 initial densities for the next 4 data's. Typically in excel, it would just be (J3-C3) but I'm having a lot more trouble with this one and any would be greatly appreciated. Do I have to install certain programs as well thank you?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSXbB.png)

Comment: `mtcars` is an inbuilt dataset.  You don't need to install

Comment: In order to subtract (or perform any columnwise operation) you need to reference the dataset the columns belong and a `$` to before specifying the column. For example, if you wanted to create a new column in the dataframe `df`, which is the difference of two existing columns, you would write `df$difference <- df$final_density - df$initial_density` ... there's other way's to do it, but this is the most basic. Make sense?